# Select rows which does not have sum equals to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `#temptable_1` and `#temptable_2`. I need to select rows which do not have rows in another table that can be subtracted. Let me clarify:

1. Row with column "Code" with "Code 1" has a "Price" that has value "-2000". Row with column "Code 4" has a "Price" that has value "2000".
   It means that if we sum this columns, then the Sum will be zero. So these both rows
   should not be selected.
2. Row with column "Code" with "Code 2" has a "Amount" that has value "-10780.56". Row with column "Code 5" has a "Amount" that has value "10780.56".
   It means that if we sum this columns, then the Sum will be zero. So these both rows
   should not be selected.
3. Row with column "Code" with "Code 3" has a "AmountIncVAT" that has value "-12936.67". Row with column "Code 6" has a "AmountIncVAT" that has value "12936.67". It means that if we sum this columns, then the Sum will be zero. So these both rows
   should not be selected.
4. Row with column "Code" with "Code 7" should be in the select result because it cannot be summed with other columns of `temptable_1`

So, columns that can be summed are: Price, VAT, Amount, AmountIncVAT

Tables looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable_1
CREATE TABLE #temptable_1 ( [Name] varchar(10), [Code] varchar(50), [id_Car] int, [PositionName] varchar(1000), 
    [Count] decimal(18,3), [id_Unit] int, [Price] decimal(15,2), [VAT] decimal(15,2), 
    [Amount] decimal(15,2), [AmountIncVAT] decimal(15,2))
INSERT INTO #temptable_1
VALUES
( '1', 'Code 1', 632324, 'Position 1', 1.000, 1036, -2000.00, -401.00, 2001.00, 2401.00), 
( '2', 'Code 2', 632324, 'Position 2', 1.000, 1036, -10780.56, -2156.11, -10780.56, 10.67), 
( '3', 'Code 3', 632324, 'Position 3', 1.000, 1036, -18780.56, -1, 558.56, -12936.67) 


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable_2
CREATE TABLE #temptable_2 ( [Name] varchar(10), [Code] varchar(50), [id_Car] int, [PositionName] varchar(1000), 
    [Count] decimal(18,3), [id_Unit] int, [Price] decimal(15,2), [VAT] decimal(15,2), 
    [Amount] decimal(15,2), [AmountIncVAT] decimal(15,2))
INSERT INTO #temptable_2
VALUES
( '4', 'Code 4', 632324, 'Position 4', 1.000, 1036, 2000.00, 402.00, 3001.00, 8101.00), 
( '5', 'Code 5', 632324, 'Position 5', 1.000, 1036, 11780.56, 2156.11, 10780.56, 18936.67), 
( '6', 'Code 6', 632324, 'Position 6', 1.000, 1036, 10580.56, 3, -21780.56, 12936.67), 
( '7', 'Code 7', 632324, 'Position 7', 8.000, NULL, 415.34, 664.54, 3322.72, 3987.26)
```

The desired result is one row with "Code 7":

```
7   Code 6  632324  Position 6  8.000   NULL    415.34  664.54  3322.72 3987.26
```

I have written the following code:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(q.Price) ORDER BY ABS(q.Price)) as CountByPrice
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(q.Vat) ORDER BY ABS(q.Vat)) as CountByVat
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(q.Amount) ORDER BY ABS(q.Amount)) as CountByAmount
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(q.AmountIncVAT) ORDER BY ABS(q.AmountIncVAT)) as CountByAmountIncVat
    , q.* 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM #temptable_1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM #temptable_2
    ) AS q
) AS q1
WHERE q1.CountByPrice =1 AND q1.CountByVat =1 AND q1.CountByAmount = 1 AND q1.CountByAmountIncVat = 1
```

Is it possible to write this code shorter?

Comment: What happens when multiple rows have the same values for a column, say `price` with different signs?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for question. Just two rows can have values with different signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
-- your input
temptable_1(Name,Code,id_Car,PositionName,Count,id_Unit,Price,VAT,Amount,AmountIncVAT)
AS (
          SELECT '1', 'Code 1', 632324, 'Position 1', 1.000, 1036, -2000.00, -401.00, 2001.00, 2401.00
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'Code 2', 632324, 'Position 2', 1.000, 1036, -10780.56, -2156.11, -10780.56, 10.67
UNION ALL SELECT '3', 'Code 3', 632324, 'Position 3', 1.000, 1036, -18780.56, -1, 558.56, -12936.67
)
,
temptable_2 ( Name , Code , id_Car , PositionName , Count , id_Unit , Price , VAT , Amount , AmountIncVAT)
AS (
          SELECT'4', 'Code 4', 632324, 'Position 4', 1.000, 1036, 2000.00, 402.00, 3001.00, 8101.00
UNION ALL SELECT'5', 'Code 5', 632324, 'Position 5', 1.000, 1036, 11780.56, 2156.11, 10780.56, 18936.67
UNION ALL SELECT'6', 'Code 6', 632324, 'Position 6', 1.000, 1036, 10580.56, 3, -21780.56, 12936.67
UNION ALL SELECT'7', 'Code 7', 632324, 'Position 7', 8.000, NULL, 415.34, 664.54, 3322.72, 3987.26
)
-- your input ends here. Real query starts here, replace comma with WITH
,
botht AS (
  SELECT * FROM temptable_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM temptable_2
)
SELECT
  *
FROM botht b
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM botht c WHERE b.price = c.price * -1
)
  AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM botht c WHERE b.amount = c.amount * -1
)
  AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM botht c WHERE b.amountIncVAT = c.amountIncVAT * -1
)
;
-- out  Name |  Code  | id_Car | PositionName | Count | id_Unit | Price  |  VAT   | Amount  | AmountIncVAT 
-- out ------+--------+--------+--------------+-------+---------+--------+--------+---------+--------------
-- out  7    | Code 7 | 632324 | Position 7   | 8.000 |         | 415.34 | 664.54 | 3322.72 |      3987.26
```

Comment: Thanks! It is really nice solution! It is awesome!